# Sync Fabric with South

Tags: python, django, migration, fabric, django-south

When i try execute a `schemamigration` with south with the following code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from fabric.api import env, hosts, local, run, cd

def updatebd():
    local('cd /Users/gian88/Sites/www/py/WEB/web/web/ && python manage.py schemamigration principal –-auto')
```

When execute the fabric says the following error:

> Migration names should contain only alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores.

When use the sentences `with cd`, the command local not recognize the url in the sentences `with cd` and says the following error:

```
can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried using `with cd` instead of `&&`? ([docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html))

Comment: When use the sentences with cd, the command local not recognize the url in the sentences with cd and says the following error: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include how you've tried to use `with cd` and what error you've got?

Comment: If you've found a solution - just answer to your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is use the command lcd, the sentences is something like this:

```
def updatebd():
    with lcd('/Users/gian88/Sites/www/py/WEB/web/web/'):
        local('python manage.py schemamigration principal --auto')
```